# Message admin doesn't preserve parent site on relocation

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

The message admin tools allow message relocation to another chat room. There also is an option for creating a new room to house the messages.

This "new room" doesn't get a parent site, which associates it with SE.com ([Like the Sandbox/Assembly/TL/Aww/etc](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?tab=site&sort=active&host=*)).

Now, these rooms cannot have their parent site changed, which I suppose is a separate [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

[image]

So basically these created rooms get stuck without a parent site.

Another mod told me this, I tested it in a simpler situation (Moved [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4848584#4848584)-->[here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3674/test-room)).

Fix please? The room ought to be associated with the parent site of the originating chat room (or allow us to choose, either way, it can be changed later).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a plain oversight; fixed now. The cloned room will have the same parent site. Note to anyone trying to find this "auto-create room" functionality: It's moderator-only.

Regarding changing the room parent: You're only allowed to do that if you're a moderator on the room's *current* parent site. For example, you can change The Periodic Table to be a cooking.se chat room, but you couldn't change it back.

If this wasn't the case, that would mean allowing you to give yourself additional powers, simply by changing any room to belong to a site that you moderate on.

Comment: (1) wait--can't room owners relocate as well as mods? (2) What additional powers does a mod get on their parent site's chat? Aside from being able to access private rooms?

Comment: (1) relocate -- yes, but the "auto-clone" part is mod-only (non-mods have to choose an existing room). (2) Currently, you get some additional information about flags in rooms that belong to your site, and there are certain things about event notifications as well (although that's not really an issue here). Once project "make parent user handling not suck" is done, expect the number of spots where it matters to increase.

Comment: Alright, I see. Keep hearing about that project, any idea when it'll be done?

Comment: It's a huge refactor, so hard to estimate.